# how to join two DataFrame and replace one column conditionally in spark

Tags: sql, scala, join, apache-spark

There are two dataframes. For simplicity, I put them as follow:

DataFrame1

```
id | name
-----------
0  | Mike
1  | James
```

DataFrame2

```
id | name | salary
-------------------
0  | M    | 10
1  | J    | 20
2  | K    | 30
```

I want to join the two DataFrame on `id` and only keep the column `name` in **DataFrame1** while keeping the original one if there is no corresponding `id` in **DataFrame2**.

It should be:

```
id | name  | salary
--------------------
0  | Mike  |  10
1  | James |  20
2  | K     |  30
```

Till now, I only know how to join two dataframes by:

```
df1.join(df2, df1("id")===df2("id"), "left").select(df2("id"), df1("name"), df2("salary"))
```

But it will use null to ignore the name value "K".

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`, which returns the first column that isn't `null` from the given columns. Plus - using `left` join you should join `df1` to `df2` and not the other way around:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df2.join(df1, df1("id")===df2("id"), "left")
  .select(df2("id"), coalesce(df1("name"), df2("name")), df2("salary"))
```

Answer (score 1):

to replace null values you can use [DataFrameNaFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html) like below...

```
    df1.join(df2, df1("id")===df2("id"), "left_outer")
.select(df2("id"), df1("name"), df2("salary"))
.na.fill(ImmutableMap.of("name", "unknown")).show()
```

where 'unknown' is sample value. you can replace with value you wanted...

if you don't want rows with null value columns

```
val joined = df1.join(df2, df1("id")===df2("id"), "left_outer")
    .select(df2("id"), df1("name"), df2("salary"))

val final = joined.where(joined.col("name").isNotNull)
final.show()
```

Also Note that  as mentioned in @Tzach Zohar  answer
[`def coalesce(e: Column*)`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) function

> Returns the first column that is not null, or null if all inputs are
>   null.

If you are looking for that kind of ... then you can go ahead.