# Join spark dataset by considering one dataset when column values match in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 spark datasets as follows

```
Dataset A :

id, mid, reputation
1   2    airline
2   3    airline
4   7    car    

Dataset B:

id, mid, reputation
1   2    bus
5   8    airline
```

I want to join (or some operation) Dataset A with B with the below output

```
  id, mid, reputation
    1   2    bus
    2   3    airline
    4   7    car
    5   8    airline
```

where its like a full outer join where there is no match between id and mid columns in both dataset, but for the matching id and mid columns, i want to Dataset A to be considered in the output.

I tried passing full and left_inner to the .join() method, but it didnt work.

Note : [how to join two DataFrame and replace one column conditionally in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960356/how-to-join-two-dataframe-and-replace-one-column-conditionally-in-spark) this does not solve the problem completely.

It does not give below line in the output, Basically when you join dataset A with B. If B has records not in A, then I want them in output as well. If A has records that B does not have , I want them in output and if there are matching records (id and mid) in A and B, then take value from dataset B

5   8    airline

Answer (score 0):

Using a `full outer join` and applying `coalesce` to all columns should work:

```sql
select 
    coalesce(tabA.id, tabB.id) as id, 
    coalesce(tabA.mid, tabB.mid) as mid, 
    coalesce(tabB.reputation, tabA.reputation) as reputation
from 
    tabA full outer join tabB on tabA.id=tabB.id and tabA.mid=tabB.mid
```

Comment: I want value from dataset B if the ids are present in both datasets.

Comment: I was able to get what i wanted with your query just by changing     coalesce(tabA.reputation, tabB.reputation) as reputation to     coalesce(tabB.reputation, tabA.reputation) as reputation. Thanks for the input. If you can modify your query i can accept the answer